# Combine 9V and 1.5V power supplies to make a 7.5V supply

Tags: power-supply

To save on cost, I wish to buy a 9V DC and a 1.5V DC power supply and connect the positive outputs together to create a 7.5V 200mA supply my Plantronics headset needs. That is, 9 - 1.5 = 7.5 across the two negatives at that point. Problems?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LM317

Comment: I'm talking about walking into Radio Shack, twisting it by hand and using tape, not creating from scratch

Comment: Buy a 10.5V or 12V DC power supply instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1.5V supply will have current trying to flow in reverse through it from the 9V supply. If it were a battery there may be some problems with some technologies but because it's a power supply and more than likely uses a diode bridge, I don't think you'll find one that works: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAUoj6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The diode bridge presents a good technical reason it might not work at all, thanks for the insights on internals of construction

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a shopping question. That said, your reason for not using one supply is cost. [A PS like that is really cheap. Here is one of hundreds of examples for only $7.](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ATL-Technology-AC-Adapter-7-5V-700ma-P-N-TEAD-41-070700U-26-00347-/281348422408?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4181ac3b08)

Buying one supply is going to be cheaper than buying two power supplies and chaining them together.

If that is still too expensive you'd be better off finding 5AA batteries and putting them in series.

Comment: Someone want to explain the downvote?

Comment: The OP didn’t ask for a shopping recommendation, but about the problems which might (and will probably) occur when using two voltage supplies in parallel like that.

Comment: @JonasWielicki First, he said series, read the question before you judge an answer. Second, I provided a better answer to what he was really asking, how to get a 7.5V power supply for cheap. This was his real intent as he stated he was trying to save on cost. Finding two separate supplies to make 7.5V will not be cheaper than 1 supply. Question answered. Downvote away!

Comment: The question was if there is an electrical problem doing this, as in, one will overpower, overheat, burnout, or in all expectations not work, sorry for the ambiguity, the shopping stuff was irrelevant

Comment: @maxpolk Why bring up cost at all then if you were just curious? There's only disadvantages to doing this (Andy aka explained some of them briefly), no advantages unless you happen to have these two things lying around, which you don't since you said you were planning to go to radioshack and buy these things. Is there any reason you don't want to just use a proper supply?

Comment: $35 for a new multi-voltage adapter.  I have several junk old 9V adapters laying around, I can spend less than $10 and get one new 1.5V adapter and save $20.

Comment: @maxpolk I linked a $6 adaptor that is the exact voltage you need...

Comment: @JonasWielicki: He's not really asking that, this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and his real problem is how to get a cheap supply. The Y question, that this thread has, is about his half baked solution.

Comment: @whatsisname, I haven’t looked at it from that perspective, thanks for pointing this out. I cannot undo the vote now though unless the answer is edited.

Comment: @whatsisname Thanks for that link. I've had this problem several times before and now have a good stack exchange reference! This was exactly the point I was trying to get across.

Comment: @JonasWielicki Do you know why you can't reverse a vote until edited? I was unaware of this rule.

Comment: You can’t un-downvote if the vote is older than a certain threshold.

Comment: @JonasWielicki Do you know the reason for that? Like why that is a feature implemented to SE?

Comment: Uhm, no idea. The mechanics are roughly described [in the Help Center](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down), but no reasoning or specific time threshold is given. I tried searching meta.SE, but after a while of searching, all I came up with is this: [there are soooo many exploits around undoing votes. Think about it a little while.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/why-cant-i-change-my-vote-if-the-post-has-been-edited-during-the-initial-5mn-gr/38759#comment85441_38759) (by Jeff Atwood)